# Django - Migrating models to MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, django

```
ProgrammingError at /blog/
(1146, "Table 'project.blog_category' doesn't exist")
```

Not sure what's causing this. Migrating data doesn't seem to populate the MySQL DB. I've also tried syndb.

```
root@watchtower:/project# ./manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: messages, staticfiles, watchtower
  Apply all migrations: blog, contenttypes, sessions, admin, auth
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Can I manually create the DB tables? Here is the model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import permalink

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    posted = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('blog.Category')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view_blog_post', None, { 'slug': self.slug })

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view_blog_category', None, { 'slug': self.slug })
```

Comment: did you ```manage.py makemigrations my_app_name``` before ```manage.py migrate```? Also, clarify what you mean by "migrating data".

Comment: Foreign key should not be blog.Category. Just Category.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import permalink

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    posted = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view_blog_post', None, { 'slug': self.slug })

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view_blog_category', None, { 'slug': self.slug })
```

I changed your foreign key relation from `blog.Catergory` to `Category`.

Furthermore, I would suggest to delete the migration files under `migrations` folder in your app folder. Delete all the files EXCEPT `__init__.py`. On top of this, you can also drop your database in MySQL and then apply `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` respectively (remember to create it before applying migrations).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `manage.py makemigrations` to create the migration files before you run them.